# The action 'update' could not be found for Users Controller Rails Tutorial Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please, help me to solve this issue 
Here is my users_controller file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
        # Handle a successful update.
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

Here is my edit view:

```
  <% provide(:title, 'Edit user') %>
    <% provide(:button_text, 'Save changes') %>
    <h1>Update your profile</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= render 'form' %>
        <div class="gravatar_edit">
          <%= gravatar_for @user %>
          <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">Change</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

and routes:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :users
      root               'static_pages#home'
      get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
      get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
      get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
      get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
      post   '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
      get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
      post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
      delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

    end
```

Comment: Please add a better description when asking, just your code and the question title may be not enough next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actions under your `private` block, which makes them unavailable through a route. All functions under that keyword is not meant to be used outside this controller scope. You just need to shift them to be outside the private block.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

You can keep before filters there because they are only being used within the same class.

Comment: Woow!)) Thank you so much, I spent almost a day trying to fix it :(